# nhibernate configuration throws an exception

Tags: c#, nhibernate, exception

During configuration of (persistance layer) nhibernate I get an exception. Message says that nhibernate couldn't find configuration file `hibernate.cfg.xml`. But I cheked my file and it's set to copy to output always. I store mappings and persistant classes in separate assembly. But both console project and class library project have the configuration file inside their outpt folder.

**Config file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.provider">
      NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider
    </property>
    <property name="dialect">
      NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2008Dialect
    </property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
      NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.connection_string">
      Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=KrossThoughtDB;
      Integrated Security=SSPI
    </property>
    <property name="show_sql">
      true
    </property>   
    <mapping resource="MyApp.Domain.Model.Entities.Mappings.User.hbm.xml"   assembly="MyApp.Domain" />
    <mapping resource="MyApp.Domain.Model.Entities.Mappings.Blog.hbm.xml" assembly="MyApp.Domain" />
    <mapping resource="MyApp.Domain.Model.Entities.Mappings.Post.hbm.xml" assembly="MyApp.Domain" />
    <mapping resource="MyApp.Domain.Model.Entities.Mappings.Category.hbm.xml" assembly="MyApp.Domain" />
    <mapping resource="MyApp.Domain.Model.Entities.Mappings.Feedback.hbm.xml" assembly="MyApp.Domain" />
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Also I use the NHibernate session helper implementation that was provided in official documentation on NHibernate.

**Session Helper**

```
public sealed class SessionHelper
{
    private const String CurrentSessionKey = "nhibernate.current_session";
    private static readonly ISessionFactory sessionFactory;

    static SessionHelper()
    {
        sessionFactory = new Configuration().
            Configure().
            BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var currentSession = context.Items[CurrentSessionKey] as ISession;

        if(null == currentSession)
        {
            currentSession = sessionFactory.OpenSession();
            context.Items[CurrentSessionKey] = currentSession;
        }

        return currentSession;
    }

    public static void CloseSession()
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;
        var currentSession = context.Items[CurrentSessionKey] as ISession;

        if(null == currentSession)
        {               
            return;
        }

        currentSession.Close();
        context.Items.Remove(CurrentSessionKey);
    }

    public static void CloseSessionFactory()
    {
        if(null != sessionFactory)
        {
            sessionFactory.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And then I call this code inside my sample console application

**Client code**

```
private static void Main(String[] args)
{
    // the next line exception's thrown
    using(var session = SessionHelper.GetCurrentSession())
    using(var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
    {
        // some actions...
        tx.Commit();
    }
}
```

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the following *.config file structure is present:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
         <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
    </configSections>
    <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
     ....
    </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up a property of hibernate.cfg.xml "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always".

Comment: As I said previously the option is already set. Build action: content. Copy to Output: copy always. All mappings are treated as embedded resources. Maybe I got some sort of typo, but I can't see it.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, I did not notice.